# Валидация корневого доверенного X509 Сертификата

Tags: c#, .net, валидация, x509certificate

Задача:

Требуется проверить на валидность все сертификаты в хранилище корневых доверенных сертификатов, покопавшись в "гугле", нашел такой вариант:

- для каждого сертификата строить `X509Chain`, возник вопрос, каким образом работает данный код, точнее каким образом проверяется валидность сертификата?

  ```
      X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
      store.Open(OpenFlags.MaxAllowed);

      X509Certificate2Collection certificates = store.Certificates;

      foreach (X509Certificate2 cert in certificates)
      {
          X509Chain chain = new X509Chain();
          chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.Online;
          chain.Build(cert);

          ... 
          bool revoked = false;
          foreach (X509ChainElement element in chain.ChainElements)
          {
              revoked = element.Certificate.Verify();
          }
      }
  ```

Так же существует такой вариант - у меня есть XML-документ, в котором содержится информация о всех нужных мне УЦ, у каждого УЦ есть статус сертификата и список url на CRL-файлами со списками отозванных сертификатов, каким образом я могу прочитать список отозванных сертификатов из CRL-файла на C# и верифицировать корневой сертификат по этому CRL-файлу?

Ищу оптимальный вариант валидации всех корневых сертификатов (~700 штук) написанный на C#

Answer (score 1):

У вас два вопроса. Первый - как работает, второй -- ищу алгоритм/готовый код. Со вторым не подскажу, а пока писал про СОС/CLR - появилась правка вопроса. Мне кажется, что как проверяется вы уже и сами поняли.

И всё же пара слов. Корневые сертификаты в Windows либо понапиханы самим майкрософтом, либо шаловливыми руками с админскими правами (сисадмины, вирусы). За корневые сертификаты самой винды можете не беспокоиться -- их удаляют и ставят через windows update и корпорация за этим внимательно следит. А вот самостийные какие-то УЦ -- это большое зло.

Ну а ваш код как работает -- он проверяет [онлайн](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509revocationmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), не полагаясь на "вчерашние" (протухшие) СОС, а запрашивает в режиме реального времени. Все сертификаты в цепочке должны быть валидными с неистёкшей датой, не числиться в СОС.

СОС кстати не качайте слишком часто -- их по регламенту всё равно обновляют не каждые пять минут, а несколько раз в сутки (может варьироваться). А нагрузка на сервера СОС всегда приличная, некоторых так и хочется отстрелить.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, вопрос такой, для, как вы выразились,  "самостийных"  сертификатов каким образом ищется СОС.
"СОС кстати не качайте слишком часто" - в планах запускать обработку раз в 48 часов

Comment: См в сертификате поле "Адреса распространения CRL"